# Focus and select another input text field with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When the user hits `TAB` on a specific field, I would like the focus to jump to a another specific field (and select everything there).

And I would like to avoid using tabindex. The default order is usually fine, and I can't be bothered to manually manage them.

I tried with `onblur` and `onkeyup` events, but everything results in twisted effects and bugs.

E.g., I tried:

```
<input id="field1" onblur="document.getElementById('anotherField').focus();" type="text">
```

This almost seemed to work, but the text in the target field was not selected.

Then I tried

```
<input id="field1" onblur="document.getElementById('anotherField').focus(); document.getElementById('anotherField').select();" type="text">
```

This almost seemed to work, but then the text of the target field would not get *unselected* upon further tabbing.

Comment: I recommend you read about [the `tabindex` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex), because you are re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I already mentioned tabindex, and my reason for not wanting to use that approach.

Comment: *"I can't be bothered to manually manage them"* You can be bothered to write inline "onblur" handlers, but not manage tab order? Strange.

Comment: Because I only have a request for one specific jump on the whole page. All the other tabbing is fine by default. As soon as I started defining tabindices, the order gets messed up whenever I insert new fields (and forget to adjust tabindices, this has already happened, I'd like to avoid it in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```js
function myTab(event, targetId) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        target.focus();
        target.select();
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="field1" value="field1" onkeydown="myTab(event, 'field2');">
  <td><input type="text" id="field3" value="field3" onkeydown="myTab(event, 'field4');">
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="field2" value="field2" onkeydown="myTab(event, 'field3');">
  <td><input type="text" id="field4" value="field4" onkeydown="myTab(event, 'field1');">
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, missed it

Comment: I can convert this to normal javascript, no problem. Will test now.

Comment: Any special reason why I should use keydown instead of keyup?

Comment: I think (not sure) that the normal script that happend when pressing tab will happend first and then this key.

Comment: So far, that seems to work great, thank you very much! The only thing I added was the select() after the focus().

Comment: Confirming that for me, this only works with onkeydown, and not with onkeyup.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below sample code

```html
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1"  placeholder="textbox1" onfocus="document.getElementById('t2').select()"/><br><br>
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t2" placeholder="textbox2" value="abc"/><br><br>
<input type="text" name="t2" id="t3" placeholder="textbox3"/><br><br>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this suggestion. It looks like it would "skip" t1. Also "t2" is written twice.

Comment: It would jump to second textbox and select the value onfocus of textbox 1

Comment: That makes no sense to me, sorry. I still want to be able to tab through every field.